# Multiple lines text always full width on React-Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing this issue with RN,
If there is only one line, the View auto fit the width with the Text inside.
But if there's multiple lines text, the Text node always uses its maximum width, so it left a blank space.

How can I resolve this?

Here is my code

```
// Style
StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginRight: 60,
        marginLeft: 0,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#F3F3F3',
        borderRadius: 13,
    },
text: {
    color: '#000',
    fontSize: 15,
    lineHeight: 21,
    includeFontPadding: false,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    flexShrink: 1,
    flexGrow: 0,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
}
})

//Render
<TouchableOpacity style={this.style.container}>
 <Text style={this.style.text}>{content}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is the results, it's left the blank space on the right

[image: react-native multiple line text issue]

Comment: this is native android behavior

Comment: I see the Facebook messenger app is not facing this problem on Android.
There must be a solution to this mess.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same issue, only on Android.

Answer (score 0):

In this case , according to me , this is because your next word 'flex-start' is a single word and won't fit in that line , try doing it with a small word like " is " and then check , if you still face a problem , just dont give a fixed width to the touchable opacity , and let me know if someother help is needed .

Comment: No, I can't use another word.
These words are posted by users who using my app.

Comment: Okay so in that case it will adjust itself according to the device width only ,
if the device width gets increased , the content will automatically shift

Comment: Either way i can help you if you can create a snack of the same :)

Comment: No, I want the width fit with the content, not related to the device width.